# delete duplicate records, keep one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a temp table created from a `copy` from a CSV file and the result includes some duplicate ids. I need to delete any duplication. I have tried the following:

```
delete from my_table where id in
    (select id from (select count(*) as count, id
        from my_table group by id) as counts where count>1);
```

However this deletes both the duplicate records and I must keep one.

How can I delete only the 2nd record with a duplicated Id?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this temp table just a single column?  DISTINCT will keep them of course....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query deletes all IDs that have a count greater than 1, so it removes everything that is duplicated. What you need to do is isolate one record from the list of duplicates and preserve that:

```
delete
from   my_table
where  id in     (select   id
                  from     my_table
                  where    some_field in (select   some_field
                                          from     my_table
                                          group by some_field
                                          having   count(id) > 1))
and    id not in (select   min(id)
                  from     my_table
                  where    some_field in (select   some_field
                                          from     my_table
                                          group by some_field
                                          having   count(id) > 1)
                  group by some_field);
```

**EDIT** Fixed :P

Comment: @Irit: Point taken! Fixed :) My example is for multicolumn data; if there's only one column (ID), then the OP should put a PK constraint on the ID column and run the import again!

Comment: Dammit: Made another mistake... OK: It's fixed now and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have foreign key relations...

```
CREATE TABLE "temp"(*column definitions*);

insert into "temp" (*column definitions*)
select *column definitions*
from (
        select *,row_number() over(PARTITION BY id) as rn from "yourtable"
) tm
where rn=1;

drop table "yourtable";

alter table "temp" rename to "yourtable";
```